# Need help trying to set an object on a daily basis until i decide to change it

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

this may sound bizarre to read, but i got this component (react-native-calendar-strip), and my idea is to click on a day and create an object to display, starting from that day and beyond

[image]
i click on that day, and in a second screen i select a bunch of items that will be displayed on the first screen.

[image]

```
{2020-05-28: Array(2)}
2020-05-28: Array(2)
  0: {title: "CODELCO - CONTRATO LEGACY y SHAREPOINT - SWD-PROY", cliente: "Axity", tipoProyecto: "Tradicional", idCliente: "4", idTipoProyecto: "2", …}
  1: {title: "Celula One Pay FX", cliente: "Banco Santander", tipoProyecto: "Agil", idCliente: "7", idTipoProyecto: "1", …}
length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
```

the object here is saving a list of elements INSIDE the date.

here is my issue. i've been told that the object should be displayed from that day AND beyond, UNTIL i click on "Editar Favoritos" (depending on which day i clicked) where i edit the object and at that moment, the object will be displayed from that day and beyond, EXCEPT, those those from previous days.

what's the best approach for this issue? help :(

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to take would be to have a start date and an end date for your data instead of using the date as the key which will make things really complex. This will make it easier for you to store in your database as well.
The calendar component you use utilizes moment which will make things easy for you.
Based on the start date and end date you can display the item in the grid.
The below component would give you the sample approach. You have to filter the data array based on the selected date. To show an item on multiple date you just have to update the end date.

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, title: 'test 123', startDate: moment('2020-06-01') },
  { id: 2, title: 'test item 2', startDate: moment('2020-06-01') },
  { id: 3, title: 'test item 3', startDate: moment('2020-06-02'),endDate: moment('2020-06-07')},
  { id: 4, title: 'test item 4',startDate: moment('2020-06-04'),endDate: moment('2020-06-06')}
];

const Planner = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(moment('2020-06-01'));

  const filteredArray = data.filter(item => {
    if (item.startDate && !item.endDate) {
      return selectedDate.isSame(item.startDate);
    }
    if (item.startDate && item.endDate)
      return (
        selectedDate.isBetween(item.startDate, item.endDate) ||
        selectedDate.isSame(item.startDate) ||
        selectedDate.isSame(item.endDate)
      );
    return false;
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <CalendarStrip
        style={{ height: 150, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}
        onDateSelected={prop => setSelectedDate(moment(prop))}
        selectedDate={selectedDate}
      />
      <View>
        {filteredArray.map(item => (
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps.